# Runtime Error in Searching a record in a Single Linked List Program

Tags: c++

I am writing a simple program for a single linked list to store data for cars(using the class Car), their name(20 char long), model no.(some integer value) and the price(some float value) of the car. However, the program shows error when I search for a particular record(entry) in the list using the function below. I just want to search for a particular record by entering the model no. For that I have a START pointer to point to the first node &
current, previous pointers to traverse through the list. The program works fine until the first "if" block. As soon as it enters the while loop dialog box pops up saying program.exe has stopped working. I can't find the error in the program which causes it to crash. Thanks in advance!

```
void car_search(int m)
{
    if(record_empty())
    {
        cout<<"\nThe list is empty. Enter some records first!\n";
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        Car *previous,*current;
        previous=START;
        current=START;
      while(m>= current->model_no && current!= NULL)
        {
            previous=current;
            current=current->next;
        }
    if(previous->model_no!=m) cout<<"\nRecord not found. Try a different model no.\n";

    else
        {
            cout<<"\nRecord found\n";
            cout<<"Model number is    "<<previous->model_no<<endl;
            cout<<"Name of the car is "<<previous->name<<endl;
            cout<<"Cost of the car is "<<previous->price<<endl;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: change m>= current->model_no && current!= NULL to current!= NULL && m>= current->model_no

Comment: Thanks! Its working. But why is this code showing an error? I don't see any difference in logic between the two.

Comment: It's the difference between "look before you leap" and "leap before you look". It should be obvious how these two approaches may lead to wildly different outcomes.

Comment: The `&&` stops on the first false value.